# Filter top(1) display by COMMAND=abc OR COMMAND=xyz

Tags: top, filter

I'm experimenting with the top(1) program, and I'm trying to figure out how to display only specified program names. For example, if I invoke a command line like

```
$ ssh localhost sleep 15
```

I'd like to be able to filter top's display to show only processes whose program names are `sshd` and `sleep`.

When top is running, if I press 'O' (uppercase oh == case-sensitive filter) and add a filter `COMMAND=sshd`, then I see what I expect: top displays only those processes whose program names start with `sshd`. If I delete that filter (press '=') and create a new filter `COMMAND=sleep`, I see the processes whose programs begin with `sleep`.

However, if I create two filters where filter 1 is `COMMAND=sshd` and filter 2 is `COMMAND=sleep`, then top doesn't display anything at all, even when there are running `sshd` and `sleep` processes. So apparently this method of filter creation produces an `AND` relationship: show if `COMMAND=sshd` && `COMMAND=sleep`.

So how do I create a filter (or filter set) that produces the desired OR relationship: show if `COMMAND=sshd` || `COMMAND=sleep`?

Answer (score 0):

With open source you can look at the code and see if it might be easy to do what you want. On my old rpm-based Fedora, I could easily download and unpack the source with

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/top
procps-ng-3.3.10-11.fc24.x86_64
$ dnf download --source procps-ng
$ rpm -i procps-ng-3.3.10-11.fc24.src.rpm 
$ rpmbuild -bp ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/procps-ng.spec --nodeps
$ cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/procps-ng-3.3.10/
```

and the code is in `top/top.c`. Looking for the word *filter* eventually shows that function `other_selection()` is implementing the `o` or `O` command  with a small C struct in which `sel = strcasestr` or `sel = strstr` is being set for input such as `COMMAND=somestring`. You can see the [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/00ec24411464d85b24973982eaaaaf367c36363c/top/top.c#L3675) code for this release. It has changed since, but is similar.

A means to implement an *or* between 2 strings looked a little difficult, but a simple alternative seems to accept a regular expression instead of just doing a string comparison. You can then just change the assignment to `sel = myfunction` and write a function that takes 2 strings and does a `regexec()` instead of `strstr()`.

If you prefer not to download and compile the program, you can write a small shim to load in front of the C library that overrides the `strstr()` function with your own. However, I found this function was used in other places by `top`, so I preferred to override `strcasestr()`, which seems to be only used for the `o` command. Create a file `shim_strcasestr.c` with the following:

```
/* capture calls to a routine and replace with your code
 * https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463461/119298
 * gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o shim_strcasestr.so shim_strcasestr.c */
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed to get RTLD_NEXT defined in dlfcn.h */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <regex.h>
#define NUMMATCH 1 /* max num matching capture groups in pattern */
char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle){
    static char *(*real_strcasestr)(const char *haystack, const char *needle) = NULL;
    regex_t myexpn;
    regmatch_t matches[NUMMATCH] = {0};
    if (!real_strcasestr) {
        real_strcasestr = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "strcasestr");
        char *error = dlerror();
        if (error != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if(needle[0]!='/') return real_strcasestr(haystack,needle);
    int rc = regcomp(&myexpn, needle+1, REG_EXTENDED);
    if(rc!=0)return NULL;
    rc = regexec(&myexpn, haystack, NUMMATCH, matches, 0);
    regfree(&myexpn);
    if(rc==REG_NOMATCH)return NULL;
    return (char*)haystack;
}
```

and compile it as shown in the comment. You can then run it as `LD_PRELOAD=./shim_strcstr.so /usr/bin/top` and when you type the `o` key, you can enter, for example, `COMMAND=/sshd|sleep` and get the desired result. I added a check for an initial `/` in the string so you can still get the original anycase matching if you omit it.  Obviously, this code can be optimised to cache the `regcomp()` result.